# Spring boot - why can't my application find static resources?

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, spring-boot

I am giving Spring Boot a go and can't access CSS, images and JS files.

I've this @SpringBootApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` file reads:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<schema>?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.name=<sql-databasename>
spring.datasource.username=<sql-username>
spring.datasource.password=<sql-password>
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
server.context-path=/<application-name>
server.display-name=<application-name>
server.port=8080
server.session.cookie.max-age=3600

# SPRING MVC (WebMvcProperties)
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=true
spring.mvc.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy
spring.mvc.locale=pt_BR
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=accept-header
spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup=-1
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**

# SPRING RESOURCES HANDLING (ResourceProperties)
spring.resources.add-mappings=true
spring.resources.cache-period=1
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/**,classpath:/public/**

# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
```

Purely by still not fully understanding how Spring Boot works, I haven't been able to shake this configuration file off:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.g.c")
public class CmsBootApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    @Description("Spring message resolver")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    @Description("Spring locale resolver")
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("classpath:/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver() {
        return new UrlTemplateResolver();
    }
}
```

Static resources are located here:

```
src/main/resources
    static
        css/
        img/
        js/
```

But, when I try to access any static resource like, like, for instance on the browser call bellow:

`http://localhost:8080/<application-name>/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`

The result is:

{"timestamp":1472734923645,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/cms/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"}

But the file **is** there...

I glanced through but couldn't find the solution at the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf).

What am I doing wrong and how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `spring.resources.static-locations` from your config unless you want to change it, `/static/` is included by default.
Resourced *inside* the `static` directory are included on the http path.
When referencing the resources you don't include `static`.
The file `src/main/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css` should be available on `http://localhost:8080/appname/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 2):

Static folder is mapped directly to the root URL, so you will access these files by root URL + path relative to static folder fe.

`localhost:8080/css/style.css`